# Task was destroyed but it is pending in my parser

Tags: python, python-asyncio

There is a parser on async + aiohttp + lxml

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os
import time
import logging
import lxml.html
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from contextlib import suppress
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

limit = asyncio.Semaphore(100)  


headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'}

url_main_list = ["https://technical.city/en/cpu/history", "https://technical.city/en/video/history"]

main_type = "https://technical.city"

def to_string(node):
    return lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')

async def request(client, url):
    global limit, headers
    while True:
        async with limit:
            try:
                async with client.get(url, headers=headers) as r:
                    log.info('Запрос: %s', url)
                    return await r.text()
            except:
                time.sleep(1)


def get_html (request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request)

async def crawl(future, client, pool):
    futures = []
    urls = await future
    for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
        parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future))
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)

async def start_main(root_urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as pool:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            initial_future = loop.create_future()
            initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
            await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
def parse(page_text):
    global count
    urls = []
    html = get_html(page_text)
    url = html.cssselect('link[rel = "canonical"]')[0].get('href')
    print("URL:", url)
    breadcrumbs = html.cssselect('div.breadcrumbs>span.almost_bold')[0].text
    if (breadcrumbs == "History"):
        pagination = int(html.cssselect('div.rating_pagination.pagination>span')[0].text)
        if(pagination == 1):
            a_list = html.cssselect('div.rating_pagination.pagination>a')
            for a in a_list:
                urls.append(main_type + a.get("href"))
        href_list = []
        a_list = html.cssselect('table.rating.responsive>tr:not([class])>td[style="text-align:left"]>a')
        for a in a_list:
            href_list.append(main_type + a.get("href"))
        href_list = list(set(href_list))
        for href in href_list:
            urls.append(href)
    else:
        type = html.cssselect('div.breadcrumbs>span[itemprop = "itemListElement"]')[1].cssselect('a')[0].get('title')
        group_list = html.cssselect('div.tbt2.row_heading>div>h2')[1:]
        title = html.cssselect('meta[property = "og:title"]')[0].get("content")

        tables = html.cssselect('div.tbt1.single>div.table')
        for index, table in enumerate(tables):
            tbts = html.cssselect('div.tbt5')
            for tbt in tbts:
                divs = tbt.cssselect('div')
                one_block = divs[1].text
                if(one_block == None):
                    break
                two_block = divs[2].text
                if(two_block == None):
                    try:
                        two_block = divs[2].cssselect('span')[0].text
                    except:
                        two_block = divs[2].cssselect('a')[0].text

                if(two_block == "+"):
                    two_block = 1
                else:
                    if(two_block == "-"):
                        two_block = 0
                group = group_list[index].text
                print(one_block, ":", two_block)

    return urls
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(url_main_list))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
    log.info('Time work: %s',time.time() - start_time)
```

In the parse method, the page type is determined and parsed. After the parser is completed (more than 2 hours), and maybe due to an error, messages appear

**Error:**

```
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6CA8>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6D38>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6D08>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6C78>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6BE8>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6C48>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6B88>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x00000218EFBE6978>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000021959BFF468>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,933 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:186> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000021959BFF3A8>()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436]>
2018-11-16 08:13:35,935 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

**In debug mode:**

```
2018-11-16 21:45:18,943 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
    source_traceback: Object created at (most recent call last):
      File "D:/Git/technical.city.py", line 222, in <module>
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(url_main_list))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 555, in run_until_complete
        self.run_forever()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 523, in run_forever
        self._run_once()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1750, in _run_once
        handle._run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
        self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
      File "D:/Git/technical.city.py", line 193, in crawl
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
    task: <Task pending coro=<crawl() running at D:/Git/technical.city.py:187> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000002A0E1BE6A08>()] created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:377> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:436] created at D:/Git/technical.city.py:193>
```

In debug mode with few links

```
2018-11-17 19:06:51,230 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B98CB8FD8>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:323> took 0.125 seconds
2018-11-17 19:06:59,041 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B994C5DF8>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:66> took 0.266 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:00,849 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B990C9E58>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:66> took 0.203 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:02,770 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B994D7378>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:66> took 0.265 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:03,600 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B9910EE28>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:66> took 0.500 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:04,055 WARNING:Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000018B990B7FD8>(<Future finis...events.py:377>) created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:66> took 0.453 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:05,587 INFO:poll 2735.000 ms took 1531.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:08,990 INFO:poll 14063.000 ms took 1250.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:10,255 INFO:poll 12797.000 ms took 1250.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:15,466 INFO:poll 11500.000 ms took 5171.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:17,050 INFO:poll 5797.000 ms took 1047.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:19,574 INFO:poll 4563.000 ms took 2344.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:20,964 INFO:poll 2204.000 ms took 1375.000 ms: 1 events
2018-11-17 19:07:22,120 WARNING:Executing <TimerHandle cancelled when=149422 _weakref_handle((<weakref at 0...0018B98CDCAC8>, '_cleanup')) at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:579 created at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:593> took 0.328 seconds
2018-11-17 19:07:25,250 INFO:poll took 1563.000 ms: 1 events
```

I understand that the start_parse method ends faster than the tasks, but I do not understand how to fix it. Advise something or make recommendations on the code.
version Python: 3.7

Comment: Can you create a minimal and _runnable_ example that would show the same problem?

Comment: @user4815162342 update code, removed the code associated with adding to the database

Comment: The definition of `request` appears to be missing.

Comment: @user4815162342 sorry, add code

Comment: It seems this error occurs only when added to the database. As a DBMS I use MySQL.  I can provide an sql query to create the database structure